# how to use switch case?

Tags: php

how can i use following in code in switch case:

```
if($_GET['test']=='') {  $test='demo';} else {  $test=$_GET['test'];}
if($_GET['test1']=='') {  $test1='demo';} else {  $test1=$_GET['test1'];}
if($_GET['test2']=='') { $test2='demo';} else { $test2=$_GET['test2'];}
if($_GET['test3']=='') { $test3='demo';} else { $test3=$_GET['test3'];}
if($_GET['test4']=='') { $test4='demo';} else  { $test4=$_GET['test4'];}
if($_GET['test5']=='') {  $test5='demo';} else {  $test5=$_GET['test5'];}
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: I think someone needs to learn about [for loops](http://php.net/for)

Comment: @Kolink this is test script.variables are different in origional script.so i cant use for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why use a `switch` here? You can just use a simple `foreach` and create the variables using [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
foreach (array('test', 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5') as $var) {
    $$var = isset($_GET[$var]) ? $_GET[$var] : '';
}
```

Alternatively, look into [`filter`](http://www.php.net/filter_input_array)

Comment: if you just made test a multidimensional aray it would be even easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a ternary operator ( http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4 )

```
$test = $_GET['test'] == '' ? 'demo' : $_GET['test'] ;
$test1 = $_GET['test1'] == '' ? 'demo' : $_GET['test1'] ;
.. etc ..
```

Although just iterating through repetitive variables could be done with a loop far easier.